# Download multiple files simultaneously with variable in URL with Curl

Tags: linux, bash, web, curl

So I have a little bash script:

```
for store in {4..80}
do
  for page in {1..200} 
  do
    curl 'https://website.com/shop.php?store_id='$store'&page='$page'&PHPSESSID=sessionID' -O
  done
done
```

The script is working but downloads all 200 store pages of all stores from 4-80 one after another, which takes a lot of time.
(Notice the bash variable store and page in the curl URL)

My goal would be to run as many curl requests simultaneously for each store/page instead getting it worked on one after one, to save time.

Is this possible?

Comment: Append one space and `&` to your `curl` command?

Comment: keep in mind that 'just' adding ` &` on the end of the `curl` command will spawn upwards of 15K+ concurrent `curl` calls (in reality your OS will probably choke/periodically-hang and/or some calls will complete before you get to the end of the 15K+ calls); even if your OS can juggle 15K+ concurrent `curl` calls chances are your network and/or disk are going to turn into bottlenecks (ie, excessive thrashing will degrade overall performance); so you'll want to look at putting a limit on the number of concurrent `curl` calls you have outstanding; (google) search on `bash limit number of jobs`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`curl` can run loops itself. This limits `curl` to 100 simultaneously sessions:

```
curl 'https://website.com/shop.php?store_id=[4-80]&page=[1-200]&PHPSESSID=sessionID' -O --parallel --parallel-max 100
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing you script as follow:

```sh
for store in {4..80}; do
  for page in {1..200}; do
    curl 'https://website.com/shop.php?store_id='$store'&page='$page'&PHPSESSID=sessionID' -O &
  done
done

# Wait for spawned cURLs...
wait
```